# Would I rather use Core Data or save files to the system?

Tags: ios, mobile, swift-language

I'm developing an iOS app which basically fetches a JSON from a remote location, parses it and instantiates classes for a couple of its elements. For some visualization, this should give you a basic idea of what my json looks like:

```
{
  "match": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "1960-01-01",
      "team 1": 1,
      "team 2": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "1960-01-02",
      "team 1": 1,
      "team 2": 3
    }
  ],
  "team": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Team Red"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Team Green"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Team Yellow"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON can get quite heavy, once it's completely filled. For my current demo-system I'm talking of 40k lines and ~2 MB file size, but it could easily get way beyond that with my live data. Obviously I'm not loading everything at once, but instead loading the bare basics, that include a couple of required IDs, so I can then make API requests to fetch just the IDs I need for whatever I want to do.

In Swift I've implemented each of the JSONs arrays for further processing:

```
class Match
  - id
  - date
  - teams

class Team
  - id
  - name
```

To save traffic and not have each user to reload everything every time they start the app I want to cache the results, more specifically save them somewhere. But here is where it gets tricky, and where my question lies:

Should I rather create a CoreData representation of each element in order to save them via Core Data and query through them, or could I just save the resulting JSON to the file system, load it once the app starts and re-parse it at that point?

The main advantage of Core Data is from my understanding that I can actually query through my entries and link them, so I could more easily ask *"What's the name of the teams from match #1?"*. Are there any other advantages for me to use Core Data, and which (dis)advantages could you see in writing the JSON file to the disk?

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend CoreData over an ad hoc solution.

1)  It's faster than loading and parsing raw `NSData` every time you need information.  CoreData does some caching implicitly and you only have to store the information that's relevant to you (thus smaller file size too).

2)  It is a core framework so there is a tremendous amount of support available for any issues you encounter.  Whereas, a custom file storage is going to have problems very specific to your use case and be very difficult to get help with.

3)  There are a number of CoreData 3rd party libraries that remove nearly all of the boilerplate code that it requires; almost to the point that `NSManagedObject` classes can be treated like any object.  (caveat: `NSManagedObjectContext` `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectModel` still need to be set up, but there are code templates for each).

The query-able aspect is a plus and with relationships it's tremendously easy to jump from object to another related object.

Ultimately, the learning curve is steep, but I found it very worthwhile once I got a good working prototype.

Comment: OK, but what about using to Core Data to store the raw JSON. Meaning, you will have a Core Data entity with two fields: ID and JSONData. ID will help you fetch the correct entity from Core Data, and JSONData will hold the information, from which you can parse a new complex object into memory. (this solution involves no file system)